# How to read from a file at the end of my program that is time stamped

Tags: python, file, printing, save

I have a program that is pretty much done that saves user input to a file with date and time appended to the file name. The problem is when the user selects not to order any more hard drives, I want it to read from the file that saved all of the user's input. How can I do that if the file name is always changed (date and time)?

I got the date and time with the file name (orders) working and saving the output (print) to the file.

```
import time
    timestr = time.strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")
    with open("/tmp/orders" + timestr + ".txt", "a+") as file:
      file.write("\n\n**** Order Summary ****\n{0}\nNumber of HD's: {1}\nDisk Slot Position(s): {2}\nDisk Size(s):{3}GB\nDimensions: {4}\n\n".format(row, b, c, d, e))
    file.close()
    ui = raw_input("Would you like to order more hard drives?(y/n) ")
    if ui == 'n':
    endFlag = True
```

how can I read from the created file so that the user can see a summary of what was written to the file?

Comment: How does the date correlate to the file data other than the time it was saved. You will need to know what file to open before opening it. I suggest using a database for this use case or save to one file not a bunch of files with no correlating names. Also the data you're saving is going to be very hard to load back into data as you're formatting it more to be human readable than as an actual data schema.

Comment: Thanks Jaba. I'm trying to find a way to have it save the input to a file that will have a unique file name because they will be saved to a tmp directory that is used by multiple users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create the timestamp just once, at the top of the program, and then use some other element (such as order number) in the filename.

```
/tmp/orders20190129-192501-order1.txt
/tmp/orders20190129-192501-order2.txt
/tmp/orders20190129-192501-order3.txt
/tmp/orders20190129-192501-order4.txt
```

This way you know all the files from this order will start with     `/tmp/orders20190129-192501`.

Comment: Thanks John. I get what you're saying about the timestamp at the top, but how would I implement what you're showing about order number? How would that work if multiple people are using the app?

Comment: I got it! Thanks John Gordon. Just putting the timestamp at the top fixed it. Thank you!